# How can I create a module using npm?

Tags: npm, module, bioinformatics, hpc

I am quite new to the IT world, but I am very fascinated and I am starting to move to bioinformatics.

I have been accredited to work on the university's HPC, which use Scientific Linux. As far as I understood I cannot install software and packages as I do on my own PC, but I have to create a module and then add the module to my environment.

There are several bioinformatic packages which I can download from GitHub. Copy the packages I am interested in, `npm init` to create a .json file, and then `npm install` package.json. But I've got several errors as output, claiming that is not a module. My guess is that my index.js is wrong, but I don't know how and to be honest I am not really sure about what I am doing.

The main question is:

Can every kind of script be converted to a module?

Comment: This is unclear - what do you mean by "copy the packages"?  What are the specific errors?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but it helped me in the past when people pointed me to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Be sure to read it well and try to reformulate your question, you'll see that it will be easier to get meaningful answers...
Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I wrote copy but I meant clone [git clone http://.....] 

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open .....
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open .....
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: Hi Pitto, you are complitely right. The point is that is not clear  in my mind the problem, and for this I can't explain really well. the main point I thik is: what files do I need to create a module with npm?

Comment: Can you give an example of bioinformatic package which you would like to install?

Comment: this is the one I need now: [4Cseq](https://github.com/younglab/fourfold)